# Why does moving the string variable give error here?

Tags: rust

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
#[derive(Clone,Debug)]
pub enum Address {
    Ptr(Box<Node>),
    None,
}

#[derive(Clone,Debug)]
pub struct Node {
    connection: String,
    value: i32,
    next: Address,
}

impl Node {

    pub fn new(connection:String, value: i32) -> Node{
        Node{
            connection,
            value,
            next: Address::None,
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, connection: String, value: i32) {
        match self.next {
            Address::Ptr(ref mut v) => {
                v.insert(connection,value);
            }
            Address::None => {
                self.next = Address::Ptr(Box::new(Node{connection,value,next:Address::None}))
            }
        }
    }
    
}


struct GraphAdj {
    vec_edge: HashMap<String,Node>
}

impl GraphAdj {
    pub fn new() -> GraphAdj{
        GraphAdj{
            vec_edge: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: String) -> Result<(),String> {

        if self.vec_edge.contains_key(&value) {
            return Err(format!("Key already present"))
        }

        self.vec_edge.insert(value,
            Node::new(String::from(""),-1)
        );
        Ok(())
    } 

    pub fn add_connection(&mut self, 
        source_vertex: String,
        destination_vertex: String,
        cost: i32,
    ){

        for (key,value) in self.vec_edge.iter_mut() {
            if *key == source_vertex {
                value.insert(destination_vertex,cost);
            } 
        }
    }

}
fn main(){}
```

I get the following error

```
***cargo check
    Checking rust_graph v0.1.0 (D:\projects\DSA\graph\rust_graph)
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `destination_vertex`
  --> src\main.rs:36:30
   |
30 |         destination_vertex: String,
   |         ------------------ move occurs because `destination_vertex` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
36 |                 value.insert(destination_vertex,cost);
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
error: aborting due to previous error***

***For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `rust_graph`
To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.***
```

I get that the String variable is moved, but why is it an issue here? I mean i am not using it afterwards anyway.

Comment: The code you shared seems unrelated to the error. The name "destination_vertex" in your error doesn't appear in the code. Please include an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ok i  will update it, seems i can not update questions, will post a new question

Comment: You can update questions using the "Edit" link underneath it.

Comment: ya sorry, updated it now

Comment: You *do* use it afterwards: you use it in a loop. The value is moved the first time the loop runs, so it is unavailable the *second* time the loop runs.

Comment: @Jmb So i guess i am supposed to use a refernce to String here ?

Comment: You probably just need to `clone()` destination_vertex: `value.insert(destination_vertex.clone(), cost)`. There is no way around the clone because `Node::insert` takes an owned  `String`, so you must give it one.

Comment: If `key` is unique in the vector, then you can `break` or `return` after inserting the value. Otherwise, like @user4815162342 said, you need to clone `destination_vertex` so that you get to keep a copy for future iterations.

Comment: thanks for ur help guys. I got it running using clone(), a quick question tho, so if  *Node::insert* takes a reference then this code would have no issue ?

Comment: If it takes a reference, then you will have to deal with the lifetimes.

Comment: `insert()` could take a reference, but it must still create a real `String` to create a `Node` with. So it will either have to create an owned string then (which is equivalent to requiring the caller to `clone()`) or you'll need to change `Node` to store a reference, which will require attaching the lifetime information to `Node` and making sure that `Node` doesn't outlive the strings. In other words, you almost certainly _don't_ want to use references there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the function where the error occurs:

```rust
   pub fn add_connection(
        &mut self,
        source_vertex: String,
        destination_vertex: String,
        cost: i32,
    )
    {
        for (key, value) in self.vec_edge.iter_mut() {
            if *key == source_vertex {
                value.insert(destination_vertex, cost);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the definition of `insert()` where we get the error:

```rust
pub fn insert(&mut self, connection: String, value: i32)
```

So you have a `String` instance which you try to move multiple times, by passing it as argument to `insert()`. Each invocation of the loop will **move** the string, and after you move it once, you will not be able to move it again.

The compiler has no way of knowing how many iterations this loop will have or how many times the condition `*key == source_vertex` will evaluate to true, so it assumes that it may happen multiple times.

In order to resolve the error you either have to `clone()` the string and move (pass as argument) the clone:

```rust
  for (key, value) in self.vec_edge.iter_mut() {
       if *key == source_vertex {
           value.insert(destination_vertex.clone(), cost);
       }
  }
```

or break from the loop once the value has been moved:

```
for (key, value) in self.vec_edge.iter_mut() {
    if *key == source_vertex {
       value.insert(destination_vertex, cost);
       return; // or break; -> exit from the loop or method
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. DId not know that recursion would confuse compiler like that, But makes sense tho.